# Function won't work as I want them to work (c)

Tags: c, function

I have to make a program that will read a .txt file. In this .txt file are measurments of a laserbeam on a sensor with a blade infront of it that is blocking the beam. Slowly this blade goes down and the light intensity is being measured. I have to make a program that will calculate the width of the laserbeam with the measurements in the txt file (the formula is been given, (((0,9*max)-(0,1*max))/1,28).

But if I do this without functions it works just fine. But there are some demands for this program. I have to use function. You might think that my program is bit devious but that is mainly because I have to make it this way. If somethings are confusing please ask me for more explanation and I'll give it you right away.

This is my current program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define ROW 45
#define COLUMN 2

  FILE *measurements;
  float x,width, intensity, a[ROW][COLUMN]={0}, total_2 = 0, maximum = 0;
  float max = 0, min = 0, difference_1 = 0, difference_2 = 0, w = 0;
  float background=0, amount=0, total_1=0;
  int menu=0, check_1 = 0, check_2 = 0, min_2 = 0, max_2 = 0;

  //Functions
  float background_radiation(float a[ROW][COLUMN]);
  float average_maximum(float a[ROW][COLUMN]);
  float beam_width(float a[ROW][COLUMN], float maximum);

//Integers for loops
  int i = 0, r = 0, k = 0, d = 0;

main()
{
  measurements = fopen("PATH\\TO\\TEXT\\FILE\\.txt", "r");
  rewind(measurements);

//Menu
  printf("Menu: \n\n");
  printf("1. Calculate background_radiation: \n");
  printf("2. Calculate average maximum signal: \n");
  printf("3. Calculate beam width: \n");
  printf("4. All measurements: \n");
  printf("5. Quit \n\n");
  printf("\nChoose:\n");

  scanf("%d", &menu);
  rewind(measurements);

//All data in array
  while(!feof(measurements))
  {
      for(i=0; i<45; i++)
      {
          fscanf(measurements, "%f%f", &a[i][0], &a[i][1]);
      }
  }

//Menu loop 
 while (menu!=5)
 {        
        switch(menu)
        {
                    case 1: printf("\n------ background_radiation ------ \n");
                            //case check
                            check_1 = 1;

                                     x= background_radiation(a);
                                     for(i=0; i<45; i=i+1)
                                     {
                                              a[i][1]=a[i][1]-x;
                                     }             
                            break;

                    case 2: printf("\n------ Maximale signaal ------ \n");
                            //case check
                            check_2 = 1;

                            y = average_maximum(a);

                            break;

                    case 3: printf("\n------ beam_width ------ \n");
                            //check if the cases 1 and 2 are used
                            if(check_1 == 1 && check_2 == 1)
                            {
                                z = beam_width(a, y);
                            }                      

                            else
                            {
                                //If case 1 and 2 aren't used
                                     printf("The backgroundradiation and maximum output aren't calculated\n");

                                     printf("You have 2 options:\n");
                                     printf("1. Use the first and last measurements to calculate the beamwidth.\n");
                                     printf("2. Choose an other option of the menu.\n");
                                     scanf("%d", &d);
                                  //Print the beam width
                                     if(d==1)
                                     {
                                             printf("\nBeamwidth:\t%f mm", ((a[0][44]-a[0][0])/1.28));
                                     }
                            }
                             break;

                    case 4: printf("\n------------ Measurements ------------\n\n");
                            rewind(measurements);
                            while(!feof(measurements))
                            {
                                  fscanf(measurements, "%f%f", &a[i][0], &a[i][1]);
                                  printf("\t%2.2f mm\t\t%2.2f V\n", a[i][0], a[i][1]);
                            }
                            break;
        }
        rewind(measurements);
        printf("\n\nChoose an option: ");
        scanf("%d", &menu);
}

fclose(measurements);
return 0;
fflush(stdin);

}

float background_radiation(float a[ROW][COLUMN])
{ 
      printf("\nHow many numbers would you like to take an average?\n");
      scanf("%d", &amount);

      for(i=0; i<amount; i++)
      {
          total_1 = total_1 + a[i][1];
      }

      //Calculate average
      background = total_1 / amount;
      printf("\nThe average background_radiation:\n%2.2f\n", background);

      return(background);                                 
}

float average_maximum(float a[ROW][COLUMN])
{      
      printf("\nHow many numbers would you like to take an average?\n");
      scanf("%d", &amount);

      for(i=44; i>(44-amount); i--)
      {
          total_2 = total_2 + a[i][1];
      }

      //Calculate average
      maximum = total_2 / amount;
      printf("\nAverage maxixum signal:\n%2.2f\n", maximum);
      return(maximum);
}

float beam_width(float a[ROW][COLUMN], float y)
{
    max = 0.9 * y;
    min = 0.1 * y;

    //Find a point in array
    for(r=0; r<45; r++)
    {
        difference_1 = max - a[r][1];
        if ((difference_1 < difference_2) && difference_1 > 0)
        {
         max_2 = r;
        }
        difference_2 = difference_1;
    }

    difference_2 = 100;

    for(k=0; k<45; k++)
    {
        difference_1 = min - a[k][1];
        if (difference_1 < difference_2 && difference_1>0)
        {
           min_2 = k;
        }
        difference_2 = difference_1;
    }

    //calculate width with the given formula
    w = (a[max_2][0] - a[min_2][0]) / 1.28;
    printf("\nBeamwidth:\t%2.2f", w); 
    return(w);          
}
```

The text file consist of two columns and 45 rows. The first column is the height of the blade down. So if its 0. It means that the blade is totally blocking the beam. The second column is the light intensity. It always has a value because of light around the sensor (background radiation). Here is the text file:

```
0.00 0.25
0.10 0.20
0.20 0.18
0.30 0.21
0.40 0.23
0.50 0.30
0.60 0.30
0.70 0.40
0.80 0.50
0.90 0.80
1.00 1.30
1.10 1.80
1.20 2.30
1.30 3.80
1.40 4.50
1.50 6.30
1.60 8.04
1.70 10.55
1.80 13.10
1.90 16.20
2.00 19.80
2.10 22.56
2.20 25.10
2.30 29.90
2.40 31.20
2.50 33.44
2.60 36.80
2.70 41.05
2.80 40.83
2.90 43.40
3.00 44.44
3.10 44.90
3.20 45.40
3.30 46.00
3.40 46.30
3.50 46.50
3.60 46.60
3.70 46.50
3.80 46.35
3.90 46.40
4.00 46.60
4.10 46.30
4.20 46.00
4.30 45.90
4.40 46.00
```

You might think that it's weird that the second column is dropping at the beginning but that has to do with accuracy of measurement.

Thanks you so much!

**What isnt working?:**

All the functions (background_radiation, average_maximum, beam_width) won't work.
The output of case 1 is(always):
1.#J

Output of case 2 (always):
0.00

Output of case 3
if case 1 and 2 are used:
0.00
else
works fine

Comment: You need to give a sample i/o of what is not working exactly.

Comment: What happened when you tried to use a debugger?

Comment: With the debugger: it seems to skip the for loop in the functions.

Comment: Variable scoping... all global... sigh.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code doesn't compile when `y` and `z` are not defined.  Adding `float` in front of those variables and altering the path to run this I found the following errors:

First, loading the data into `a` failed for me:

```
a[ROW][COLUMN] = {0}
```

produced a garbage array so I dropped the initialization to get just:

```
a[ROW][COLUMN]
```

allowing the data load to work.

The next issue is that you want to treat `amount` as both a float and an int.  In background_radiation() I made an extra arg for the loop and altered the scanf():

```
scanf("%f", &amount);

int max = (int)amount;
for(i=0; i<max; i++)
```

After those changes if I enter "12.0" for the `amount` float, I get the following output:

```
------ background_radiation ------ 

How many numbers would you like to take an average?
12.0

The average background_radiation:
0.54
```

average_maximum() can be made to work similarly.  beam_width() was probably suffering from data load issues.  It appeared to work fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

Case 1 never calls `background_radiation()`.

The line :

```
float background_radiation(a);
```

is a (re-)declaration of a function called background_radiation.
If you turn on warnings in your compiler you will get a warning for it. You probably meant:

```
background_radiation(a);
```

There may be other bugs as well.

Comment: Turn on warnings in your compiler. Fix the warnings! Then ask again if you still have problems.